# how to normalize a barplot to normal distribution in R?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, gaussian

I created a barplot using ggplot in which the x-axis represents a number in acending order and each number has is own percentage. I would like to normalized the observed barplot (Gaussian) in order to compare the two barplots. someone know how to do it?
Here is my code:

```
lemon_imp_05 = subset(Lemon_brevante_data,Lemon_brevante_data$Block == "IMP-05")
  S = lemon_imp_05$percentage
  names(S) = lemon_imp_05$count
  barplot(S, main = 'Block IMP-05 Loam',
          xlab= 'Count(N.fruits/carton)',ylab = 'percentage(%)', col = "green")
```

The result is a non normal distribution bar plot, but I want to force a normal distribution on the observed barplot (don't know how to add picture of the current result).
any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Normalize your data. `barplot(S / sum(S), ...)`. Though this would be a sum-to-one normalization, not a Gaussian normalization. You could use `scale(S)` instead if you want to center and scale the vector. If you edit your question, in the edit bar there's an "add image" button.

Comment: Do I need to write: barplot(scale(S),...) ? and in barplot(S / sum(S),...) I can't see any difference. or maybe I don't write it in the right position

Comment: Could you share some sample data? Something like `dput(S[1:10])` for the first 10 values would be great - it will be copy/pasteable and include all structure and class information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to plot the `densitity` distribution of your empirical data, and compare it to a normal distribution with same `mean` and `sd`?

```
plot(density(y), ylim=c(0, .5), lwd=2)
curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(y), sd=sd(y)), add=TRUE, lwd=2, lty=2, col=2)
```

[image]

Like this?

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
y <- rnorm(1e2, mean=1.5, sd=.8)
```

Or use `hist`.

```
h <- hist(y, freq=F, breaks="FD")
curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(y), sd=sd(y)), add=TRUE, lwd=2, lty=2, col=2)
```

[image]

```
## stored values
h
# $breaks
# [1] -1.0 -0.5  0.0  0.5  1.0  1.5  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5
# 
# $counts
# [1]  2  2  6 15 21 23 17 11  3
# 
# $density
# [1] 0.04 0.04 0.12 0.30 0.42 0.46 0.34 0.22 0.06
# 
# $mids
# [1] -0.75 -0.25  0.25  0.75  1.25  1.75  2.25  2.75  3.25
# 
# $xname
# [1] "y"
# 
# $equidist
# [1] TRUE
# 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "histogram"
```

Comment: exactly. but I would like to see it as barplot and to be able to extract each relevant percentage of the non dependent x values

Comment: I still have some problem.. maybe I should explain in other way. 
I created a bar plot in which the x-axis is with numbers and the y-axis is with the relevant percentage.
this is the code:
s= golden_reynders_sa_2020_gaussian$percentage
names(s)= golden_reynders_sa_2020_gaussian$diameter
barplot(s, col = "green")
if I try to get the gaussian normalization using:
curve(dnorm(s, mean = 46, sd= 8.94, add= TRUE, lwd= 2, lty= 2, col= 2))
I have an error says: 'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'...
maybe you can help with this situation?
thanks

Comment: @ErezKauffman I'm sure you will figure it out when you take more care of the parentheses, i.e. which arguments belong to which function (here we have two of them wrapped). You can always get help of a function by typing e.g. ?curve or help(dnorm) into the R console.